# Replace text in all wiki-s

Tags: fogbugz

Is it possible to replace some text in all wiki's/cases on fogbugz server? I have lots of wikis which have links to other wikis but links were created using ip address of old server, now server changed and all those links are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions, but unfortunatelly they only work on client side:

- use BugMonkey Customization to re-write the links on the front-end
- use GreaseMonkey to do the same thing, but using firefox addin

Fixing this on server side requires manual modifications from FogBugz UI or issuing sql query on server.